How to fix the vscode folders layout with "fixed" folders?
'Fixed' folders in vscode explorer
These folders are "fixed" in the top of explorer side. I've been trying to found the option to disable this feature, but i dont found what is that feature name.
I want them just to look like the code, dont fixing nothing in the top of it.
My bad the low quality english, it's not my main language.

Use ChatGPT or similar to improve your english.

The term you're looking for is "Sticky Scroll", it's a new VSCode feature.
To disable it, go to Settings > Workbench > Tree: Enable Sticky Scroll and uncheck the box:

